# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupshelpers==1.0

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to build a Docker Image for my app but I keep getting the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupshelpers==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cupshelpers==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
```

Does anyone know what I can do? I feel like it has to do with the ubuntu version but I can't find out which one to use.

What I also tried is adding `RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools` or replacing `RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip` with `apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev` but I keep getting errors. Maybe I am completely misunderstanding something here? I am new to Docker and I have only (successfully) built a hello world image without requirements or flask, just a simple print command.

here's my Docker:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:20.10

MAINTAINER Your Name "sarah.loeffler@ohs-engineering.de"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

COPY ./requirements.txt offline/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /offline

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /offline

ENTRYPOINT [ "flask" ]

CMD [ "run" ]
```

and here's my requirements.txt:

```
alembic==1.5.7
ansible==2.8.18
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==2.1.0
asttokens==1.1.13
automationhat==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
blinker==1.4
blinkt==0.1.2
buttonshim==0.0.2
Cap1xxx==0.1.3
certifi==2018.8.24
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.3.7
colorzero==1.1
cookies==2.2.1
cryptography==3.3.1
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.0
distlib==0.3.1
distro==1.5.0
docutils==0.14
dominate==2.6.0
drumhat==0.1.0
entrypoints==0.3
envirophat==1.0.0
evdev==1.4.0
ExplorerHAT==0.4.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Migrate==2.7.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
fourletterphat==0.1.0
gpiozero==1.5.1
greenlet==1.0.0
guizero==0.6.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.6
importlib-metadata==3.7.3
ipykernel==4.9.0
ipython==5.8.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.13.2
Jinja2==2.10
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-core==4.4.0
keyring==17.1.1
keyrings.alt==3.1.1
kiwisolver==1.0.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
logilab-common==1.4.2
lxml==4.3.2
Mako==1.1.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
microdotphat==0.2.1
mote==0.0.4
motephat==0.0.3
mypy==0.670
mypy-extensions==0.4.1
nudatus==0.0.4
numpy==1.16.2
oauthlib==2.1.0
olefile==0.46
pantilthat==0.0.7
parso==0.3.1
pendulum==2.1.2
pexpect==4.6.0
pgzero==1.2
phatbeat==0.1.1
pianohat==0.1.0
picamera==1.13
pickleshare==0.7.5
picraft==1.0
piglow==1.2.5
pigpio==1.44
Pillow==5.4.1
pipenv==2020.11.15
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
psutil==5.5.1
pycairo==1.16.2
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pycparser==2.20
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
pyflakes==2.0.0
pygame==1.9.4.post1
Pygments==2.3.1
PyGObject==3.30.4
pyinotify==0.9.6
PyJWT==1.7.0
pylint==2.2.2
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pyserial==3.4
pysmbc==1.0.15.6
python-apt==1.8.4.3
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-editor==1.0.4
pytzdata==2020.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==5.4.1
pyzmq==17.1.2
qtconsole==4.3.1
rainbowhat==0.1.0
reportlab==3.5.13
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
responses==0.9.0
roman==2.0.0
RPi.GPIO==0.7.0
RTIMULib==7.2.1
scrollphat==0.0.7
scrollphathd==1.2.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
selenium==3.141.0
semver==2.0.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
sense-emu==1.1
sense-hat==2.2.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
skywriter==0.0.7
sn3218==1.2.7
soupsieve==1.8
spidev==3.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
ssh-import-id==5.7
thonny==3.3.6
tornado==5.1.1
touchphat==0.0.1
traitlets==4.3.2
twython==3.7.0
typed-ast==1.3.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
uflash==1.2.4
unicornhathd==0.0.4
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==20.4.3
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
visitor==0.1.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
WTForms==2.3.3
zipp==3.4.1
```

Comment: There is no `cupshelpers` at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/cupshelpers/ . You need to find out where from you can install it. AnaConda, perhaps?

Comment: uhm okay... 
I'm not using AnaConda, my application is made with flask and I installed everything with pip install. Do you think I can try sudo apt-get? 
what I can't generally understand is why I even need to install it when I never intended to. Why is it even in my requirements?

Comment: "*Why is it even in my requirements?*" Because it was installed as a dependency of another package?

Comment: yes of course but how can I handle it? I want to use the requirements.txt and not manually name all the modules I installed but with these dependencies I obviously can't use the requirements.txt